# Trying to get to homebrew on my Wii RVL-001

Tags: nintendo-wii, homebrew

I bought used Wii. Waiting on new remote. I have compatible Wii/GameCube controller. Anyway to get to homebrew so I can play GameCube?

Comment: Do you *need* homebrew? The Wii natively supports playing GameCube games

Comment: I not sure...not worried about the warranty... But I have the GameCube remote plugged in and it a compatible controller for model RVL-001...But it's not responsive... I guess I need the Wiimote to operate anything...which I want receive for a while...just want to play...I got 007 GoldenEye: Rouge Agent on GameCube...I figured if I could get to homebrew... I could play...My first Wii...lol!!